# Bigger number typed by user in a for loop java, error "bad operand type"

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need to create a program in Java that:

-Asks for 10 different numbers.

-Tells the highest number.

What I did:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BiggerValue {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int bigger;
   int[] n = new int[10];
   System.out.print("Please enter " + n.length + " values:");
   for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      n[i] = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println(n[i]);
    if(n < n[i]) {
        bigger = num[i];
       }
     } 
      System.out.println("The highest number is " + bigger);
   }
}
```

I don't know if I am doing it right. I get an error in compilation `< n[i])`

```
Bad operand types for binary operator '<'
first type:int[] second type:int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is array type, which is causing the error. They the following code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BiggerValue {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int bigger = 0; //you need to initialise this
   int[] n = new int[10];
   System.out.print("Please enter " + n.length + " values:");
   for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
      n[i] = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println(n[i]);
    if(bigger < n[i]) { //you should compare it with bigger, not n.
        bigger = n[i]; //there is nothing called num[i], it is n[i]
       }
     } 
      System.out.println("The highest number is " + bigger);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare an array to an `int`.

What it looks like you meant to do is to compare the `bigger` variable to the just-entered number to determine if the highest number needs to be updated.  Replace

```
if(n < n[i])
```

with

```
if (bigger < n[i])
```

In addition, you'll also want to give `bigger` an initial value that is less than any value you anticipate, e.g. `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  Also, `num[i]` is a typo; you must have meant `n[i]`.